# Changing Woocommerce Product Image thumbnail size

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to make the gallery thumbnails on the Woocommerce single product page the same size as my main product image. I know I can set the size with this

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function($size ) {
    return array(
        'width' => 487,
        'height' => 487,
        'crop' => 0,
    );
});
```

But I would like to keep small 100x100x Woo thumbnails for the cart page. I read in the Woo docs that you can change which image sized is being used, so I tried

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail_size', function( $size ) {
return 'woocommerce_single';
});
```

but this is not working. Any thoughts why?

Comment: Because "woocommerce_single" is the size of the large image, check "woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail". Text from the Woo docs: "woocommerce_single shows the full product image, as uploaded, so is always uncropped by default. It defaults to 600px width.

woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail is always square cropped and defaults to 100×100 pixels. This is used for navigating images in the gallery."

Comment: Yes, but by using this function you should be able to change what image WOo is using.

Comment: Yes, using it with the appropriate size on return. What did you use on return?

Comment: My product image size is set to 550 x 550 px in Customizer -> Woocommerce

Comment: What size does it returns it at? If it's the default size, try regenerating your media gallery

Comment: It still shows the 100x 100px image, even after regenerating all thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

There are some hooks available. If you want to change the size using below hook

add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_src', 'your function name', 50, 4 );

Source:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html
https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using CSS, setting a specific size for the cart page:

```
table.shop_table img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: No, this will just make for a blurry image because Woocommerce is by default using a 100 x 100 px thumbnail for this.

Comment: If you change thumbnail default size for 487x487px?

Answer (score 0):

The correct snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', function( $size ) {
    return 'thumbnail'; //replace 'thumbnail' with required size name or array()
} );
```

Comment: My website broke after using this snippet